# How to manipulate with multi collection in MongoDB when we using ASP.NET API Core2.1

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In Microsoft Tutorial that explain How to Create a web API with ASP.NET Core and MongoDB 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

They have one Collection in MongoDB "Books", and when we configure connection to connect to this collection we add some codes in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<BookstoreDatabaseSettings>(
        Configuration.GetSection(nameof(BookstoreDatabaseSettings)));

    services.AddSingleton<IBookstoreDatabaseSettings>(sp =>
        sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<BookstoreDatabaseSettings>>().Value);

    services.AddSingleton<BookService>();

    services.AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

My question:
What if I wan to manipulate with multi collections rather than one "Books"?
If I have 3 collections: Books, Anthers and Libraries, Should I add

```
services.AddSingleton<BookService>();
services.AddSingleton<AntherService>();
services.AddSingleton<LibraryService>();
```

Also what about 20 collections?

Answer (score 1):

You can register a single Instance of the IMongoDatabase in your Services container. then you can add Singleton Collections to your services container using the IMongoDatabase Instance.

```
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var db = client.GetDatabase(dbName);
 
var collectionA = db.GetCollection<Model>(collectionName);
services.AddSingleton<IMongoDatabase, db>();
services.AddSingleton<IMongoCollection, collectionA>();
```

to use these you would expose your collections to your services via the constructor.

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
   private readonly IMongoCollection<SomeModel> _someCollection;

   public SomeService (IMongoCollection<SomeModel> someCollection)
   {
      _someCollection = someCollection;
   }
}
```

Then after that you can access the IMongoCollections through your Services (BookingService, AntherService, LibraryService)

you can also add multiple collections to a single service. which allows multiple collection data manipulation.