# ASP.NET Core Web API and MongoDB with multiple Collections and multiple Databases

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, singleton

With this question [ASP.NET Core Web API and MongoDB with multiple Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63648217/asp-net-core-web-api-and-mongodb-with-multiple-collections) answers I can see the perfect use of singleton and lazy initialization for mongodb's `WITH` **single** database and **multiple** collection.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Asset Model API", Version = "v1" });
        });

        ConfigureMongoDb(services);

        services.AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
    }

    private void ConfigureMongoDb(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var settings = GetMongoDbSettings();
        services.AddSingleton(_ => CreateMongoDatabase(settings));

        AddMongoDbService<AuthorService, Author>(settings.AuthorsCollectionName);
        AddMongoDbService<BookService, Book>(settings.BooksCollectionName);

        void AddMongoDbService<TService, TModel>(string collectionName)
        {
            services.AddSingleton(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IMongoDatabase>().GetCollection<TModel>(collectionName));
            services.AddSingleton(typeof(TService));
        }
    }

    private DatabaseSettings GetMongoDbSettings() =>
        Configuration.GetSection(nameof(DatabaseSettings)).Get<DatabaseSettings>();

    private static IMongoDatabase CreateMongoDatabase(DatabaseSettings settings)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
        return client.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);
    }
```

**BookService.cs**

```
public class BookService
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<Book> _books;

    public BookService(IMongoCollection<Book> books)
    {
        _books = books;
    }

    public List<Book> Get() => _books.Find(book => true).ToList();
}
```

**BooksController.cs**

```
public class BooksController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly BookService _bookService;

    public BooksController(BookService bookService)
    {
        _bookService = bookService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<Book>> Get() => _bookService.Get();
}
```

My use case: I have **multiple** databases and my API end point will accept `database name` as ONE of the argument

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<Book>> Get(string dbName) => _bookService.Get(dbName);
```

Now question is what changes requires in my `service` class and `ConfigureMongoDb` method of startup class so that I can still get lazy initialization and singleton support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of injecting the IMongoCollection into the services (BooksService, ...), you could create a class that can provide the collection based upon the database name, e.g.

```
public class MongoCollectionProvider
{
  private readonly IMongoClient _client;

  public MongoDbCollectionProvider(IMongoClient client) 
  {
    _client = client;
  }

  public IMongoCollection<T> GetCollection<T>(string database, string collection)
  {
    var db = _client.GetDatabase(database);
    return db.GetCollection<T>(collection);
  }
}
```

You can then inject this class into the services and retrieve the collection before querying the database, e.g.

```
public class BookService
{
    private readonly MongoCollectionProvider _prov;
    private readonly string _coll;

    public BookService(MongoCollectionProvider prov, string coll)
    {
        _prov = prov;
        _coll = coll;
    }

    public List<Book> Get(string dbName) => _prov.GetCollection<Book>(dbName, _coll).Find(book => true).ToList();
}
```

You can register the services like this:

```
private void ConfigureMongoDb(IServiceCollection services)
{
  var settings = GetMongoDbSettings();
  services.AddSingleton(_ => CreateMongoClient(settings));
  services.AddSingleton<MongoCollectionProvider>();

  services.AddSingleton(sp => 
  {
    var prov = sp.GetRequiredService<MongoCollectionProvider>();
    return new AuthorsService(prov, settings.AuthorsCollectionName);
  }
  services.AddSingleton(sp => 
  {
    var prov = sp.GetRequiredService<MongoCollectionProvider>();
    return new BooksService(prov, settings.BooksCollectionName);
  }
}

private DatabaseSettings GetMongoDbSettings() => Configuration.GetSection(nameof(DatabaseSettings)).Get<DatabaseSettings>();

private static IMongoDatabase CreateMongoClient(DatabaseSettings settings)
{
  return new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
}
```

If you want to constrain the databases to specific ones, you can change the MongoCollectionProvider to only accept registered database names.

Comment: Thank you very much @Markus. Can I write a common method for various `AddSingleton` for different services `AuthorsService`, `BooksService`, etc like example above `void AddMongoDbService<TService, TModel>(string collectionName)
            {
                services.AddSingleton(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IMongoDatabase>().GetCollection<TModel>(collectionName));
                services.AddSingleton(typeof(TService));
            }` ?

Comment: The problem is the collection name that changes from service to service and in addtion is configurable. If you can change this to use a constant in the service (e.g. BooksService -> collection name "Books", ...) then you do not need the factory method anymore and you can register the services as a singleton like this `services.AddSingleton<BooksService>();`.

Comment: If you need the collection names to be configurable, you could create a dedicated class, e.g. `CollectionNameProvider` that receives the configured collection names as input during service registration and provides them to the services by properties, e.g. `BooksCollectionName`. The services need a constructor parameter for the collection name provider and can pick the configured collection name from the provider.

Comment: Thanks. Also I need to pass more than one collection for service class `return new BookService(dbCollectionProvider, settings.BooksCollectionName, settings.AuthorsCollectionName)`. It's make sense not to use some common method. Thanks for all your help. :)